# Calculate time taken for SQL Query execution and to convert rows to java objects in mybatis

Tags: mysql, profiling, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a sql query in mybatis which outputs around 35000 records. I want to calculate the time taken for the query execution and then to convert those output rows into java objects separately. This query is taking nearly 3 sec. But when the query is executed directly in mysql workbench it takes only 0.003 sec.

Comment: Please explicitly ask a question rather than making it implicit and please show your code

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do that using only mybatis logging or something like that.

The problem is that these two phases of query execution are not clearly separated. Some part of converting of the data retrieved from database happens in JDBC driver itself and some part is done in mybatis mapper.
There's also time spent to send the data from the database to your program (make sure that it is accounted for when you run the query in workbench).

Your best bet is to use profiler and probably run the query in the loop and then check in profiler where the time is spent.